# Cannot insert into MySql Db from android php connection

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I'm making a little [MySql Crud](https://github.com/FabioNevesRezende/SimpleCrudMySqlAndroid) using Android-Studio and the data fetching is working just well but I cannot insert into db and I think the problem may be because of lack of permission to write (maybe?).

Anyway, in a given point, the user is at [`Register.java Activity`](https://github.com/FabioNevesRezende/SimpleCrudMySqlAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/apps/fabio/appmysql2/Register.java) and presses button to register. This calls the method `onClick()` on `switch case R.id.BtRegs`. This calls a `registerUser` method which calls the [`ServerRequests class`](https://github.com/FabioNevesRezende/SimpleCrudMySqlAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/apps/fabio/appmysql2/ServerRequests.java). In the `doInBackground` I `try` to connect to my localhost using the IP of my network lan calling the [`Register.php`](https://github.com/FabioNevesRezende/SimpleCrudMySqlAndroid/blob/master/Register.php) with `POST` method.
It does not return anything from Register.php.
How do I check if it is indeed a lack of permission of some other thing? I think it may be no permission because the same methods used to fetch data worked well.

Here is the part of the code on `ServerRequests class` which does the connection:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Map<String,String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();


        dataToSend.put("name", user.name);
        dataToSend.put("age", String.valueOf(user.age));
        dataToSend.put("username", user.username);
        dataToSend.put("password", user.password);

        String encodedStr = getEncodedData(dataToSend);
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try{

            URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "/Register.php");

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            con.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

            writer.write(encodedStr);
            writer.flush();
```

And this is the `Register.php` which does the MySQL insert:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO tabuser (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**note:** Considering `SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.x.x"`
and `$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");` is normally set on main proj.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your localhost? Your device's localhost will be your device, not your computer.

Comment: It is actually set to my computer on local network (something like 192.168...) I just uploaded the project with localhost. Like I said, it is working fine with fetching, but not with inserting

Comment: You could try committing changes to determine whether the problem lies in autocommit being set to off?  That would cause this behavior, I believe.  You could test this by adding just a few lines of code at the end of your script, as shown here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php  It doesn't necessarily seem likely to me that this is the issue, but this is all of the advice I could offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is solved:**

As @Redbeard011010 commented, the lack of `commit` was causing this problem.

So, on the code I added:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
//do the inserting
if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
print("Transaction commit failed\n");
exit();
}
```

After this, the code is working normally and the data is being inserted into the database. 
More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php)